# Upload folder to google cloud bucket with python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I know that I can upload single files like this:

```
bucket_name = "my-bucket-name"
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

blob_name = "myfile.txt"
blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)

blob.upload_from_filename(blob_name)
```

How can I do the same with a folder? Is there something like `blob.upload_from_foldername`?
I tried the same code with replacing `myfile.txt` with `myfoldername` but it did not work.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'myfoldername'
```

This is the folder structure:

[image]

I assume something is wrong with the path but I am not sure what. I am executing the code from `Untitled.ipynb`. Works with `myfile.txt` but not with `myfoldername`.

I do not want to use a command line function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't upload an empty folder or directory in Google Cloud Storage but you can create empty folder in Cloud Storage using the client:

```py
from google.cloud import storage

def create_newfolder(bucket_name, destination_folder_name):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_folder_name)

    blob.upload_from_string('')

    print('Created {} .'.format(destination_folder_name))
```

And if you are trying to upload a whole directory, you can use the codes below:

```py
import glob
import os 
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()
def upload_from_directory(directory_path: str, destination_bucket_name: str, destination_blob_name: str):
    rel_paths = glob.glob(directory_path + '/**', recursive=True)
    bucket = client.get_bucket(destination_bucket_name)
    for local_file in rel_paths:
        remote_path = f'{destination_blob_name}/{"/".join(local_file.split(os.sep)[1:])}'
        if os.path.isfile(local_file):
            blob = bucket.blob(remote_path)
            blob.upload_from_filename(local_file)
```

Comment: thanks! destination_blob_name would be the name I want the directory to have in the bucket?